# Asymptotic expansion of a list

Tags: series-expansion

I am trying to calculate a asymptotic series expansion of a list.

```
Series[{0,-((R^2 ν (2+(-1+ν (2+ν)) Cos[2 θ]))/((-1+ν) (1+ν^2) r^2)) + 
    (R^4 ν (-7+5 ν (2+ν)+16 Cos[2 θ]+(-1+3 ν (2+ν)) Cos[4 θ]))/(4 (-1+ν) (1+ν^2) r^4) + 
    O[1/r]^6,-((R^2 ν (3+ν) Cos[θ] Sin[θ])/((1+ν^2) r^3))+O[1/r]^4,0}, {r,Infinity,3}]
```

I don't understand why the `1/r^4` term shows up in the output. Even more, I can copy & paste this input

```
Series[-((R^2 ν (2+(-1+ν (2+ν)) Cos[2 θ]))/((-1+ν) (1+ν^2) r^2)) + 
    (R^4 ν (-7+5 ν (2+ν)+16 Cos[2 θ]+(-1+3 ν (2+ν)) Cos[4 θ]))/(4 (-1+ν) (1+ν^2) r^4) + 
    O[1/r]^6,{r,Infinity,3}]
```

but evaluating the following line gives an error message about the argument

```
Series[a/r^2+b/r^4+O[1/r]^6,{r,Infinity,3}]
```

Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You have to remove the `O[_]^_` from your input:

```
Series[{0, -((R^2 ν (2 + (-1 + ν (2 + ν)) Cos[2 θ]))/((-1 + ν) (1 + ν^2) r^2)) + (R^4 ν (-7 + 5 ν (2 + ν) + 16 Cos[2 θ] + (-1 + 3 ν (2 + ν)) Cos[4 θ]))/(4 (-1 + ν) (1 + ν^2) r^4), -((R^2 ν (3 + ν) Cos[θ] Sin[θ])/((1 + ν^2) r^3)), 0}, {r, Infinity, 3}]
```

Comment: Yes, but why? I mean why can't Mathematica interpret it properly?

Comment: Because `O[1/r]^6` is just a display form for a more complicated thing. For example, if you compute `Series[x, {x, \[Infinity], 5}]`, the frontend displays a nice `x + O[1/x]^6`, but that's not the internal representation, which is `SeriesData[x, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {1}, -1, 6, 1]`, as you can discover with `FullForm`. For this reason, you can either accurately copy and paste `SeriesData`s without corrupting them or (better) leave out the `O[_]` placeholder (possibly with `Normal`).